# Pushed button signal switch on

Tags: circuit-design, components

I have a question about an circuit idea. I have one touch button (TTP223) to control switch on and off a Raspberry. Raspberry switchs on connecting one pin to gnd. How could i transform this on a hold on pulse to switch on it? I though about a IC 555 but i think is not the solution because is not a delay that I want but a hold on pulse (2 seconds, 3 seconds...).

EDIT 2: I want this: If I keep pressed the button 3 seconds, Switch on the raspberry (create that 0 signal (gnd)).

Thank you so much!

Comment: There's pushbutton on/off switches. Problem's already solved. Otherwise, you need a **latch**, not a timer (like the 555).

Comment: Sorry, actually is not a normal button, is a capacitive sensor as a button (touch button). Is there latches with time configuration?

Comment: **edit** your question to include that crucial amount of information! However, such sensors are **Way** more complex than a latch themselves, so chances are your sensor already has the capabilities you need. Generally, describe as much as possible of your system – let the experts do the abstraction :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, my mistake! Solved, i add the information. I'm using a TTP223 button (added too to the information).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a "hold on pulse"? Do you mean push to turn on, push again to turn off? Or do you mean push to turn on. push and h old for 2 or 3 seconds to turn off? Or something else?

Comment: A kept pulse button. If a keep pulsed button 3 seconds, switch on the raspberry.

Answer (score 2):

> I want this: If I keep pressed the button 3 seconds, Switch on the raspberry (create that 0 signal (gnd)).

That's impossible with the capacitive touch sensor IC you've got. It emits a pulse after it's sure it detected a touch, but the pulse contains no information on how long the button was pressed.

So, you'll need a different solution. Sounds like you'd want to use one of the very many microcontrollers that have a built-in touch sensing peripheral, use that, and write some very minimal firmware. In effect, with appropriate external hardware your RPi could do this without any chip, but my guess is you want this as hard power-off in case the software on your Pi hangs, so I'll guess this is not an option.

Comment: Yes, I supose that there is not any circuit that can do that i want, microcontroller is the solution I think.

Answer (score 0):

Your touch sensor IC has a specific pin for switching the mode between on/off switch and momentary switch.

So, your problem is already solved – just read your datasheet :)

Comment: No, that is not the solution. Raspberry doesn't mind what is the state of the switch, only minds if switch is to gnd or not (switched or not). My idea is have pushed the button 3 seconds (for example) and then, connect it to gnd (for switch on).

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question then, but to me it looks like this mode answers exactly addresses your comment!

Comment: I want this:

If I keep pressed the button 3 seconds, Raspberry switch on (create 0 signal (GND)).